# Bayesian Inference/maximum Likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am rather struggling with the gist **part d)** of this question. Why would I wish to compare the MLE with the posterior mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a prior that is accurate, then the posterior mean is always a better estimator than the MLE because the posterior mean minimizes the expected sum-of-squared error between the parameter estimate and the true value of the parameter, under the assumptions of the prior. You could also compute the mean parameter value under the likelihood distribution with no prior, but in practice people usually just maximize the likelihood which is the MLE estimate (with no prior). The reason to compare is that it often sheds light on how the Bayesian method works and how the Bayesian method generalizes the non-Bayesian method. As you can see in the explanation of the comparison, the posterior mean is a weighted average of the prior mean and the ordinary MLE value. Furthermore, the amount of weight given to the prior is directly related to the variance of the prior. This makes sense, because the more variance (more uncertainty) we have in the prior distribution, the more we should favor the data (e.g. MLE) instead of the prior. The MLE basically assumes a flat prior (infinite variance) so all the weight is put on the MLE and zero weight is put on the prior.

Comment: Cool, but why does the MLE end up depending on the data when you are considering the MLE of the distribution of Y|λ? Or is this just a specific case?

Comment: Sorry, I probably confused by using the word "data". To me, $Y$ is the "data" and $\lambda$ is the parameters. This is how statistics problems usually arise in practice, from data $Y$, and you get either a likelihood function $L(Y| \theta)$ for parameter choice $\theta$, and you can maximize $L$ over $\theta$ given $Y$, or you get a posterior distribution $P(\theta | Y)$ in the Bayesian approach, which you can also maximize or take the mean over, given $Y$.

Comment: Apologies i think I'm getting confused with the notation. Why does the order of the "given" switch when you are finding the MLE?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a typo. It's $L(\theta | Y)$ for the notation but it really means the data likelihood for the given parameters, i.e. $P(Y | \theta)$ without any prior, or equivalently, a flat prior.

Comment: @user2566092 I get that the less variable the prior is, the more knowledge we have about the value of $\lambda$ (before we have witnessed the data), however how does the fact that we have a lower variance make $E(\Lambda)=\frac{r}{b}$ more accurate?

Answer (score 2):

I would have added a comment but I don't have enough reputation points so I'll state my comment here. The MLE is essentially the posterior with a uniform prior, that is we assume we know nothing about $\lambda$. A good equation to keep in mind is:

$\text{posterior} = \frac{\text{likelihood} \times \text{prior}}{\text{data probability}}$

So the MLE is a special case of the posterior where we assume a uniform prior. Check out the following tutorial that explains this nicely.

http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/03/11/frequentism-and-bayesianism-a-practical-intro/